# Storing objects of igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have three different graphs that were produced by `igraph` package and `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` function. How can I store all three of these `(g1, g2, g3)` in one object so that later I can use this object as an input for another function. I want to preserve all the attributes of the graphs.

Here's the structure of the three graphs:

```
dput(g1)
structure(list(11, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 
9, 10, 9, 10, 10), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9), 
    c(0, 1, 10, 2, 11, 19, 3, 12, 20, 27, 4, 13, 21, 28, 34, 
    5, 14, 22, 29, 35, 40, 6, 15, 23, 30, 36, 41, 45, 7, 16, 
    24, 31, 37, 42, 46, 49, 8, 17, 25, 32, 38, 43, 47, 50, 52, 
    9, 18, 26, 33, 39, 44, 48, 51, 53, 54), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
    51, 52, 53, 54), c(0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 
    55), c(0, 10, 19, 27, 34, 40, 45, 49, 52, 54, 55, 55), list(
        c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        list(name = c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", 
        "wf", "citi", "amex", "spgl", "pnc")), list(wt = c(10000, 
        3.16222797634994, 10000, 10000, 6.2838498029626, 1.93361060894155, 
        10000, 10000, 5.84323225364297, 7.44026659903325, 1.31111055012301, 
        10000, 10000, 4.30459269702548, 2.20457094344212, 3.49673898163627, 
        3.09239540712491, 3.43107254995375, 10000, 5.64499596383733, 
        10000, 10000, 3.72116985462354, 2.70273403225818, 2.35839869470134, 
        10000, 10000, 10000, 1.83130016032325, 1.99399002493476, 
        1.7644293974645, 1.88708226743269, 7.73257077502946, 
        10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 6.94406536133693, 
        3.32018490900407, 2.0759886748923, 4.11734201102576, 
        6.193275571549, 2.85404877010956, 10000, 3.01093189825944, 
        10000, 10000, 7.07193471387249, 10000, 5.19453928016632, 
        10000, 10000))), <environment>), class = "igraph")

dput(g2)
structure(list(11, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 
9, 10, 9, 10, 10), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9), 
    c(0, 1, 10, 2, 11, 19, 3, 12, 20, 27, 4, 13, 21, 28, 34, 
    5, 14, 22, 29, 35, 40, 6, 15, 23, 30, 36, 41, 45, 7, 16, 
    24, 31, 37, 42, 46, 49, 8, 17, 25, 32, 38, 43, 47, 50, 52, 
    9, 18, 26, 33, 39, 44, 48, 51, 53, 54), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
    51, 52, 53, 54), c(0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 
    55), c(0, 10, 19, 27, 34, 40, 45, 49, 52, 54, 55, 55), list(
        c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        list(name = c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", 
        "wf", "citi", "amex", "spgl", "pnc")), list(wt = c(1.72565213162016, 
        10000, 10000, 10000, 2.60988018061569, 3.37529546067647, 
        5.68789870362681, 2.44357606642214, 4.38114633403004, 
        10000, 10000, 2.49869325166531, 10000, 10000, 4.56956459390346, 
        3.52409742807134, 2.97961673322383, 3.42809851201881, 
        3.15481552530237, 7.32112737506667, 10000, 7.0852416616783, 
        3.99494740752879, 2.65955867194822, 10000, 10000, 10000, 
        10000, 5.73934520134914, 1.80740569361977, 1.5783164909029, 
        2.84567417160359, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 5.30260309989479, 
        10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 7.06161817483184, 6.9222112543713, 
        4.63691541477454, 3.48797079504012, 6.38029319494032, 
        10000, 2.48116694808653, 10000, 2.12352867446693, 3.04335319291233, 
        10000, 10000, 5.22409020671212, 10000))), <environment>), class = "igraph")

dput(g3)
structure(list(11, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 
9, 10, 9, 10, 10), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9), 
    c(0, 1, 10, 2, 11, 19, 3, 12, 20, 27, 4, 13, 21, 28, 34, 
    5, 14, 22, 29, 35, 40, 6, 15, 23, 30, 36, 41, 45, 7, 16, 
    24, 31, 37, 42, 46, 49, 8, 17, 25, 32, 38, 43, 47, 50, 52, 
    9, 18, 26, 33, 39, 44, 48, 51, 53, 54), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
    51, 52, 53, 54), c(0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 
    55), c(0, 10, 19, 27, 34, 40, 45, 49, 52, 54, 55, 55), list(
        c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        list(name = c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", 
        "wf", "citi", "amex", "spgl", "pnc")), list(wt = c(10000, 
        4.14221420842333, 2.69857209553848, 5.77115055524614, 
        1.95672007809809, 2.98690863617922, 1.92161847347613, 
        2.34571882319417, 10000, 10000, 1.97201563662035, 5.4078452590091, 
        10000, 6.85345421615961, 3.51453278996926, 10000, 10000, 
        2.08964950396744, 10000, 2.78868220464486, 10000, 3.41857460835555, 
        4.57693796722718, 1.96044036389548, 10000, 6.69365386837721, 
        2.61525679780493, 7.34195637377719, 2.57334862699097, 
        3.54317409176484, 10000, 2.33889236077345, 2.49271973693215, 
        5.47858809426897, 10000, 5.25238753114071, 10000, 10000, 
        10000, 10000, 10000, 2.68400716970295, 2.49075030691088, 
        2.59993683645561, 10000, 10000, 2.49345951327313, 5.7338881554994, 
        1.73687483250752, 4.24032760636804, 3.11756167665892, 
        5.07827243244947, 10000, 1.69643890905687, 10000))), 
    <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

Comment: You can put them in a list `list(g1,g2,g3)`. Why type of function are you trying to pass this to later? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You showed the input but not what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `list` like below

```
g <- list(g1,g2,g3)
```

Comment: What if this list is to be saved in a file? I tried using `save(g,file="graph.Rdata")`, but it didnt work.